# git seeing everything as up to date even though I added folders locally

Tags: git, github

I went to github.com and created a new repository.

I then did `git init` on my computer, and pushed to the URL of the new repository. I added all the files in my local repository and pushed the files to the master as well. Now, I just added a new folder called `deliverables`, `product` and `sprint`, but when I do `git status` it says everything is up to date.

When I do `git add deliverables` it goes to the prompt again. When I do `git commit -m "added deliverable` it says:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

and if I do `git push` it says:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

How come it is not seeing the new folders I added when I do `git status` and it doesn't let me add or commit these folders?

I went to github.com and checked the repository and these folders are indeed not there.

Comment: Are you trying to add an empty folder?  Or is there a file in that `deliverables` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git doesn't really have a concept of folders, just files and their paths. Since there are presumably no files in these folders, there is nothing to commit.

The typical solution for this is to add an empty file named `.keep` (or whatever your preference is) in the folder so that git "knows" about the folder.